# Django testing view with pytest

Tags: django, django-views, pytest

Could you please helpe me debugging this test? I got this error (I don't know whay since, I
have no pk in view): `django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.`I think the error is due to `pk=request.user.id` passed as argument in `User objects` in the `view function`.

```
class TestViews(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
         self.client = Client()
         self.create_campaign_naming_tool_url = reverse('create_campaign_naming_tool')
         self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username = 'admin',
            email = 'admin@sigma.fr',
            password = '1234'
         )

    def test_create_campaign_naming_tool(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.create_campaign_naming_tool_url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'form.html')
```

Here is my view

```
def create_campaign_naming_tool(request):
    current_user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    form = CampaignNamingToolForm(initial={'user': current_user})
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        campaign = CampaignNamingTool(user=current_user)
        form = CampaignNamingToolForm(request.POST, instance=campaign)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your campaign haven ben\
                            success fully created.")
            return render(request, 'form.html', context)

    return render(request, 'form.html', context)
```

Comment: You did not log in a user in the client.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I don't undestand. I am already logged in my web app.

Comment: not in the `Client`...

Comment: the test client acts as some sort of mini browser, where you need to login with a user. Furthermore tests work on a different database, so with different users, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not login the user in the test:

```
class TestViews(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.create_campaign_naming_tool_url = reverse('create_campaign_naming_tool')
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username = 'admin',
            email = 'admin@sigma.fr',
            password = '1234'
        )
        self.client.login(username='admin', password='1234')

    # …
```

It also makes no sense to do such query to fetch the user: `request.user` is a `User` object, so you can work directly with this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def create_campaign_naming_tool(request):
    form = CampaignNamingToolForm(initial={'user': request.user})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        campaign = CampaignNamingTool(user=request.user)
        form = CampaignNamingToolForm(request.POST, instance=campaign)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your campaign has been successfully created.')
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'form.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.